# Fastest way to convert any string to array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently developing a GameBoyColor emulator in Javascript.

Loading a 64k ROM file into the Memory Unit takes about 60 seconds right now. This is the function:

```
loadROM: function (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function () {
        var start = new Date();
        console.log("start", start.getTime());

        this.__ROM = new Uint8Array(reader.result.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < reader.result.length; i++) {
            this.__ROM[i] = (reader.result.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF);
        }

        var end = new Date();
        console.log("end", end.getTime());

        console.log((end.getTime() - start.getTime()) + " for " + i + " iterations");

        this._trigger("onROMLoaded");
    }.context(this);

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

`reader.result` is the ROM file as string and `this.__rom` is the array. Important is the for loop where I get every single character and push it to the ROM array of the memory.

This takes way to long. So question is how to speed this thing up. Is there any better approach to convert a string into an array?

Comment: Since you want an array, why don't you use readAsArrayBuffer ??

Comment: Because I need it in binary format.

Comment: the arraybuffer will give just the same as your readstring + conversion, just faster.

Comment: but that's exactly what readAsArrayBuffer will give you. Code :  this.__ROM = new UInt8Array(reader.result);   and it's over.

Comment: And did you check that *any* value was > 0xFF ??? my guess is that none is, so in fact you just need to copy, no mask. Besides that, strings accept the array notation myString[i], no need to use charCodeAt. cache your arrays and arrays length.  -and try readAsArrayBuffer :-) -

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do it natively using `split()` instead of looping:

```
// See the delimiter used
this.__ROM = reader.result.split('');

// And to do the bitwise AND on each byte, use map()
this.__ROM = this.__ROM.map(function(i) {
    return i & 0xFF;
});
```

Or in one step (without writing to `this.__ROM` twice):

```
this.__ROM = reader.result.split('').map(function(i) {
    return i & 0xFF;
});
```

Comment: Thing is, what I forgot. I still need to access every character, because I need to scope every character to 0xFF

Comment: @JohannesKlauß - Added a solution for that as well. The speed boost however will be primarily because of the natively implemented split method.

Comment: Wow... this really is super fast! Thank you alot.

Comment: @techfoobar: I demand to see a benchmark of both approaches before calling this a "speed boost". :) I wouldn't be surprised if the overhead of the map and of the inline function wouldn't completely take away the boost of the `split()` method. Though I assumed modern JS interpreters would JIT the hell out of that.

Comment: @haylem Well techfoobars approach takes about 21 milliseconds versus 32778 seconds with my approach.

Comment: @JohannesKlauß: Right, I had misread your approach actually, my bad. Speed away!

Comment: @JohannesKlauß - and if you want to save a couple more milliseconds, you can do: `this.__ROM = reader.result.split('').map(function(i) { return i & 0xFF; });` - This way we don't write to `this.__ROM` twice :-)